# PHP Echo web address in Joomla - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a software that auto FTPs reports to the server for my clients to view. I'm trying to figure out a simple way to incorporate these reports for my Joomla users.

So this is what I have so far I thought would be the easiest.

Sample of report:
[Sample Report Here](http://www.garranteedsolutions.com/reports/progress.php?id=p-25951946357-508786)

The software generates the link and then I usually email them out. So I'm thinking add another field in the Admin > User Manager under each client to past the web address.

The on the front end use Jumi (which allows PHP and Java) in the article.

iFrame the Report Web address using the Joomla Wrapper's code and making the src dynamic. So it pulls the web address from the database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function iFrameHeight() {
var h = 0;
if (!document.all) {
    h = document.getElementById('blockrandom').contentDocument.height;
    document.getElementById('blockrandom').style.height = h + 60 + 'px';
} else if (document.all) {
    h = document.frames('blockrandom').document.body.scrollHeight;
    document.all.blockrandom.style.height = h + 20 + 'px';
}
}
</script>

<iframe onload="iFrameHeight()" id="blockrandom" name="iframe" src="http://www.garranteedsolutions.com/reports/progress.php?id=p-25951946357-508786" width="100%" height="1000" scrolling="no" class="wrapper">
This option will not work correctly. Unfortunately, your browser does not support inline frames.</iframe>
```

I've added an additional column in the database titled "Portal"

How do you write the php code to populate the web address from the "Portal" column for the user that's logged so they only see their report?